# Proof that ladder operators contains a complete set of eigenkets

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space

Ladder operators, in quantum mechanics, could be used to derive eigenkets of energy with different eigenvalues (i.e. the system's energy) by raising and lowering it.

However, is there a proof that it proves a COMPLETE set of eigenkets?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23028/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54691/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/300829/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic I'm a 2nd year undergrad who never have been exposed to Hilbert spaces -- is there any other way to prove it? (my course in Oxford is based on the book "The Physics of Quantum Mechanics" which didn't seem to have proven it)

Comment: If you don’t know anything besides the ladder operators, completeness is just an assumption you put in.

Comment: Any good book on functional analysis will prove the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) for self-adjoint operators on a Hilbert space; ladder operators are related to lie algebras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relying **only** on commutation relations of $a$ and $a^\dagger$ it is not possible to prove completeness of the produced basis by the action of $a^\dagger$ on $\psi_0$, since counterexamples can be constructed easily. If you instead refer to the whole theory, assuming  that the Hilbert space is $L^2(\mathbb R, dx)$ and $a$ and $a^\dagger$ are constructed as you know out of $X$ and $P$, you can prove completeness observing that (1) $\psi_0$ is the first Hermite function and (2) the recurrence formula of $\psi_n$, $\sqrt{n+1}\psi_{n+1} = a^\dagger \psi_n$ is the same as for the known Hilbert basis of Hermite functions. This proves completeness.