# Quantum harmonic oscillator: How can we know that the lowest eigenvalue for the operator $A^{\dagger}A$ is zero and not a positive number?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, harmonic-oscillator, eigenvalue

With operator methods we can set the Hamiltonian of the harmonic oscillator in the following form:

$$\hat{H}=\hbar \omega(A^{\dagger}A+1/2).$$

My question is that how can we know that the lowest eigenvalue for the  operator $A^{\dagger}A$ is zero and not a positive number?

Comment: You are talking of the eigenvalue of $a$ or of the Hamiltonian?
The eigenstates of $a$ are not energy eigenstates. Furthermore, there is not an eigenstate of $\mathcal{H}$ with eigenvalue 0.

Comment: There was a typo. Hope you now undertand what I'm asking.

Comment: This question is explained in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23028/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54691/2451) Phys.SE posts and links therein.