# If electrons were spinless bosons, would atomic ground state configurations necessarily have total orbital angular momentum zero?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, orbitals, ground-state

My motivation for this question comes from the periodic table. There, the many-body ground state electronic configurations of certain atoms like boron or carbon can have a nonzero total orbital angular momentum. This can be interpreted as arising from the Pauli exclusion principle if one takes the approximate picture of electrons filling a Slater determinant of single-body orbitals, some of which have nonzero orbital angular momentum. If I instead imagine that electrons were bosons, it's much more tempting that the total orbital angular momentum would be zero for all atoms regardless of the number of electrons. This would stem from an approximate picture of these bosonic electrons filling the $1s$ state repeatedly, but it's not so clear to me whether there's a nice proof of this in the presence of electron-electron Coulomb repulsion.

Is there a proof that the ground states of atoms featuring spinless, bosonic "electrons" would have total orbital angular momentum zero?

---

As an aside, I suspect that more generally there's a well-known proof that a Hamiltonian for spinless bosons of the form $H=\sum_i \left( \frac{p_i^2}{2m} + V(|\vec{r}_i|) \right) + \frac{1}{2}\sum_j \sum_{i \neq j} U(|\vec{r}_i - \vec{r}_j|)$
necessarily has a ground state of zero angular momentum.

Comment: That must be a yes. It is easy to think of a lot of electrons occupying a Helium-like gigantic spherical ground state. The inter-electron repulsion just causes the "ground state" to expand away from the standard one. The electron correlation would be horrendous to compute.

Comment: The lack of the exchange interaction would have drastic consequences, etc. In this sense the way the question is posed makes it nearly off-topic. On the other hand, Bose-Einstein condensation of bosons interacting via repulsive interactions is a well-studied subject - and this is what the question is really about, isn't it?

Comment: That sounds like a charged EB condensate, in my opinion. The wave function should be fully symmetric, no? If so, then the ground state shouldn't be that hard to compute. Am I missing something?

Comment: @RogerVadim there will be exchange interaction, but attractive rather than repulsive. Bosons clump together. Yes, BEC of bosons interacting via repulsive interactions is a well-studied subject, except that they tend to be studied in the bulk limit, i.e. has translational symmetry. But if it is at an atomic level, the finite size of atom boundary causes a lot of difficulty. Maybe this is a moot point because if electrons are bosons, maybe there would not be individual atoms either.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent You are right about exchange interaction, I meant something soemwhat different. My point is much simpler: *if electrons were spinless bosons* puts the question out of the realm of the mainstream physics, which means that according to the Phyiscs SE quidelines it must be closed (though I didn't cast a closure vote.) There are too many hypotheticals, that are not really of importance... on the other hand, asking a question about BE condensation with repulsion and in a centrally symmetric potential (if you want) would be menaingful and clear.

Comment: @RogerVadim This question is perfectly on-topic. If you are not interested in the question, move on.  Yes, the question does contain hypotheticals, but they are completely in line with what mainstream physics is interested in contemplating, and what this site allows for. OP is asking about a perfectly reasonable physical system (a system of bosonic point particles with mutual Coulombic repulsion, all attracted to a central Coulombic potential — no less hypothetical than e.g. the infinite square well), which is of clear interest to understanding the structure of quantum and atomic theory.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty The question has been answered two times over already, once formulated in more concise form, which I suggested. The duplicate was linked before you reopened it..

Comment: @Roger No, that is incorrect – you did close the question, which I have now reopened. (I don't know what you mean by "the duplicate was linked".) You obtained a gold tag badge for QM last December, which gives you a "dupehammer", i.e. the ability to unilaterally close questions with the QM tag. The convention thus far is that the dupehammer should only be used with due caution. If you want to be warned that you're about to unilaterally close a question, use [this script](https://stackapps.com/q/7466) (cf. [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231625)).

Comment: In any case, for completeness, this is the thread that was previously marked as duplicate:

Comment: Related: [Ground state of Spherical symmetric potential always have $\ell=0$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/146827/ground-state-of-spherical-symmetric-potential-always-have-ell-0)

Comment: To be clear, that is not a duplicate of this question. Both the question and the answers there address the case of a single electron. The question here clearly addresses the correlated multi-electron case. The two have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I closed it as a duplicate. Incidentally, this is the only closure reason for "duperhammer": *These users can single-handedly mark quantum-mechanics questions as duplicates and reopen them as needed.* Moreover, this answer clearly addresses the multiparticle problem, and it is them who suggested the duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/760048/247642

Comment: I think I see the subtlety with the various duplication closures. The accepted answer to 146827 of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/146994 is considering a single-particle problem and gives an AJP article considering a single-particle problem, as discussed in its abstract. However, the proof used in that paper is straightforwardly adapted to the multiple particle case for spinless bosons, as seen in answer physics.stackexchange.com/q/760048 to Roger's question 760035 inspired by mine.

Comment: @RogerVadim Furthermore, the AJP article also notes that positivity and hence non-degeneracy of the wavefunction can similarly be shown for interacting bosons in chapter 6 of Progress in Liquid Physics, from which it follows that the article's single-particle arguments for zero angular momentum can be adapted to the multiparticle bosonic case (just as dennismoore's physics.stackexchange.com/q/760048 did).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Finally, I'm of the opinion that since the answer and question to 146827 apparently are just considering single-particle wavefunctions, 760035 doesn't need to be closed as dupe. I'm fine if mine is closed as dupe of 760035 despite the latter being later and being inspired by mine, as 760035 nicely answers mine.

Comment: @user196574 I am not sure about the questions you are referring to. I closed my question (inspired by yours) as a duplicate myself. I merely tried to help you clarify the matter - scientifically speaking.

Comment: @RogerVadim Yes, I'm arguing that you shouldn't have closed your question, because it isn't a duplicate. Though the answerer of your question identified your question as a duplicate, he was incorrect - he added an important addition that is not included in the paper and question he was inspired by (namely multiple particles rather than a single particle). If you take that path, then I'm OK if my question is marked as a duplicate of your question, so that your question is the dupe target of cases where people ask about zero orbital angular momentum of *multiple* spinless interacting particles.