# Does the ground state of interacting of interacting spinless/scalar bosons in a centrally symmetric potential have angular momentum 0?

Tags: angular-momentum, symmetry, group-theory, bosons, ground-state

Motivated by this question: [If electrons were spinless/scalar bosons, would atomic ground state configurations necessarily have total orbital angular momentum zero?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/760009/247642).

Can we make a group-theoretical argument that the ground state of a system of spinless bosons in a centrally symmetric field necessarily has zero angular momentum? If not, what are the conditions for a) the existence of a zero angular momentum state, and b) for it to be the ground state?

Here is the Hamiltonian:
$H=\sum_i \left( \frac{p_i^2}{2m} + V(|\vec{r}_i|) \right) + \frac{1}{2}\sum_j \sum_{i \neq j} U(|\vec{r}_i - \vec{r}_j|)$

Comment: Does "spinless boson" mean scalar boson?

Comment: @flippiefanus yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An $L\neq0$ state would necessarily be degenerate, however, the ground state (as long as no spin effects and/or velocity-dependent potentials are present) is always non-degenerate. To see this, consider the Ansatz
$$
\Psi(\boldsymbol{r}_1,...,\boldsymbol{r}_N)=\chi(\boldsymbol{r}_1,...,\boldsymbol{r}_N)e^{i\Phi(\boldsymbol{r}_1,...,\boldsymbol{r}_N)} \ ,
$$
where $\chi(\boldsymbol{r}_1,...,\boldsymbol{r}_N)\geq0$ without loss of generality.
You can always minimize the energy
$$
{\cal{E}}=\frac{\langle\Psi|H|\Psi\rangle}{\langle\Psi|\Psi\rangle}\geq E_0
$$
($E_0$ being the exact ground state energy)
by setting  $\Phi(\boldsymbol{r}_1,...,\boldsymbol{r}_N)=\text{const.}$, which is equivalent to $\Phi(\boldsymbol{r}_1,...,\boldsymbol{r}_N)=0$. To verify this, just substitute, and then integrate by parts:
$$
{\cal{E}}=\frac{\langle\chi|H|\chi\rangle+\Delta}{\langle\chi|\chi\rangle} \ ,
$$
where
$$
\Delta=\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\int\mathrm{d}^3r_1...\int\mathrm{d}^3r_N
\chi^2(\nabla_k\Phi)^2\geq0 \ .
$$
You can always go lower in the energy by setting $\nabla_k\Phi=0$, that is $\Phi=\text{const.}$.

Therefore, the ground state wave function is always $\Psi\geq0$, meaning that no degenerate, yet orthogonal wave functions can be found (two degenerate wave functions could always be chosen orthogonal, however, this is not possible if none of them has nodes).

We can conclude that the ground state is non-degenerate, so it cannot be an $L\neq0$ state.

(This is just a trivial extension of the results of
[*Am. J. Phys*, **70**, 808 (2002)](https://pubs.aip.org/aapt/ajp/article/70/8/808/1055862/The-variational-principle-and-simple-properties-of)
for $N$ spinless particles.)

Comment: If the angular momentum is not zero, wouldn't it mean that the state is always degenerate, since we can always have a state with the opposite component of its projection on the  quantization axis: $L_z\rightarrow -L_z$?

Comment: Sure, if $L\neq0$, then we would have a $2L+1$-fold degeneracy.

Comment: Then the only non-degenerate state is $L=0$ and it must be the ground state? OR do I miss something? Btw, *You can always minimize this* - I suppose you mean we can minimize the energy (after plugging the ansatz into the SE.)

Comment: Sorry, of course I meant minimizing the energy, I'm updating the answer.

Comment: I just realized that this was actually asked [before](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/146827/ground-state-of-spherical-symmetric-potential-always-have-ell-0?rq=1), and the answer there quotes the paper I learned this proof from...