# Why the eigenvalues of orbital angular momentum $L$ never take half-integral values?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, wavefunction

In general, if a set of three hermitian operators $J_i (i=1,2,3)$ satisfy the commutation relation $[J_i, J_j]=i\hbar\epsilon_{ijk}J_k$, then it follows that the eigenvalues of $j(j+1)\hbar^2$ of $J^2\equiv J_1^2+J_2^2+J_3^2$ are given by $j=0,\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{3}{2},2,...$

The set of orbital angular momentum $L_i=\epsilon_{ijk}x_j p_k$ satisfy this commutation relation. Therefore, the eigenvalues of $L^2$ is expected to carry both integral and half-integral eigenvalues in absence of any extra conditions. But to my knowledge, in every problem, $\ell$ takes only integral values $\ell=0,1,2,3...$

What causes $\ell$ not to have half-integral values? Can it be answered using a system-independent argument?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Half-integer eigenvalues of orbital angular momentum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/153369/half-integer-eigenvalues-of-orbital-angular-momentum). See also [Why do we get wrong answers for orbital angular momentum if we solve it algebraically?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/443334/84967).

Comment: I meant these answers https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/153369/

Comment: Hi  @Valter Moretti. What matters is that the question is a duplicate, so I'm closing it. Should I merge the threads?

Comment: I agree that the question is a duplicate, but the former question is on the one hand less clear than this latter, on the other hand none of the proposed answers properly answers the question in my view: they are either wrong or confused or use particular models. Yes perhaps merging the threads is a good idea.