# Physical example of degenerate groundstate in harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, harmonic-oscillator, ground-state

It says in my lecture notes, that it depends on the hilbertspace in question weather the ground state $|0\rangle$ of an harmonic oscillator is degenerate or not. The ground state fullfills

$$N|0\rangle=0|0\rangle \quad \textrm{with} \quad N=a^\dagger a \quad \wedge \quad[a,a^\dagger]=1$$ Assuming that the ground state is non-degenerate one can proof that all states are non-degnerate and the spectrum is equal to $\mathbb{N_0}$

Can someone give an example for a space with a degenerate ground state? I've never encountered such an oscillator in my QM course.

In [Proof that the One-Dimensional Simple Harmonic Oscillator is Non-Degenerate?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23028/) the user Qmechanic relates this to Fock-Spaces. But I would appreciate a more concrete example, as this goes beyond my mathematical scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving the equation for a one-dimensional Harmonic oscillator is both a good exercise and a way of convincing oneself that it has only one ground state.

An important example of a Harmonic oscillator with degenerate ground state is the [Landau levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_quantization) of a particle in a magnetic field, where the $x$-oscillator Hamiltonian is given by
$$\hat{H}=\frac{\hat{p}_x^2}{2m} + \frac{m\omega_c^2}{2}\left(\hat{x} - \frac{\hbar k_y}{m\omega_c}\right)^2,$$
and every state
$$E_n = \hbar\omega_c(n+\frac{1}{2})$$
is inifinitely degenerate in respect to the position of the center of the oscillator:
$$x_c = \frac{\hbar k_y}{m\omega_c}.$$
This example involves Hilbert space where the wave functions are plane waves in $y$-direction, and solutions to the Harmonic oscillator equation in $x$-direction.
$$\Psi(x,y) = e^{ik_y y}\phi_n(x-x_c).$$