# How can we even assume that $a|0\rangle\neq 0$ in "Measuring the Quantum State of Light"

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

This is a followup to my previous question [Is this proof that $a|0\rangle=0$ wrong (ladder oeprators and number operator)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/719558/is-this-proof-that-a0-rangle-0-wrong-ladder-oeprators-and-number-operator)

According to the comment, we should always have $a|0\rangle= 0$, because the norm of $a|0\rangle$ is 0 which I agree with. By definition of a Hilbert space, a norm of 0 is only possible for the null vector o.

However in "ulf leonhardt measuring the quantum state of light" which a copy is available [here](https://www.fulviofrisone.com/attachments/article/404/measuring%20the%20quantum%20state%20of%20light%20-%20Ulf.pdf), in page 22, proposition 2.31, the author talks about the possibilty that $a|0\rangle\neq 0$ and explores it at the end of page 24.
How can we even make this assumption if the norm of $a|0\rangle$ is always 0 ??

Comment: ? The author *tells you*, quite clearly and emphatically, that the wavefunction of $a|0\rangle\neq 0$, so  $\varphi_{-1}(q)= \langle q|a|0\rangle$ is not normalizable, and so unacceptable, as not being in the Hilbert space. He demonstrates that. What is the problem?

Comment: So basically it's just an alternative proof ?

Comment: I am troubled by your logical path network. It is, of course, a confirming restatement that vacua not annihilated by *a* are unacceptable as not in the Hilbert space.

Comment: Thank you maybe I was just overthinking it.